# Not able to fetch "Name" of lookup fields of Link-Entity (Web API + FetchXml)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have some fetchXml that I am executing through the Dynamics CRM Web API.  THe fetchXml query is constructed like so:

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="new_someEntityA">
    <attribute name="new_lookupForSomeEntityA" />
 <link-entity alias="new_someEntityB" name="new_someEntityB" from="entityBId" to="entityAId" visible="false" link-type="outer">
    <attribute name="new_lookupForSomeEntityB" />
  </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

When I send this query through the Web API, I get a response and the value for "new_lookupForSomeEntityA" includes the value (GUID) and a Formatted Value (it's name).  But the response for "new_lookupForSomeEntityB" includes just the GUID and I can't find a way to get it's GUID and value.  I've added a header record for:

```
"Prefer": "odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"
```

but that appears to just get me formatted values for the primary entity and not the link entity.  Is this a limitation of the Web API or am I doing something wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to add the name attribute to the `<link-entity>` node?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. In SQL, the attribute is "new_lookupForSomeEntityBName" and if I add that, I get a return that says that attribute doesn't exist.  If I do it with "name" (lower case), the query returns, but still with just a GUID, no lookup name.

Comment: you need to specify the name of the name-attribute on entity new_someEntityB. You can look it up in the CRM solution on the main tab of the entity. In SQL `new_lookupForSomeEntityBName` is a column of a filtered view that maps to the primary field name of the actual table.

Comment: I changed it to:
    `<link-entity alias="new_someEntityB" name="new_someEntityB" name-attribute="new_name" from="entityBId" to="entityAId" visible="false" link-type="outer">
      <attribute name-attribute="new_name" name="new_lookupForSomeEntityB" />
    </link-entity>`

When I do that, I get the same id as a return value, just:
`new_someEntityB_x002e_new_lookupForSomeEntityBid: [GUID]`

Comment: Don't use `name-attribute` attributes, but only `<attribute name="new_name"/>`.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, but the lookup on the link-entity is to a different entity altogether...it isn't the primary key of `new_someEntityB`, it's a look up to some other entity that is stored on `new_someEntityB`. Again, sorry for the confusion there.

Comment: I think it’s is a limitation. Maybe good to know, but a sort of similar thing happens when you try to get the formatted value of a linked attribute with a name that is already used in an attribute of the entity. So for example when your new_lookupForSomeEntityA and new_lookupForSomeEntityB have the same name, but are instead of lookup fields, date fields(which also have a formatted value). Then only the attribute of the entity gets a formatted value.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that returns formatted values for link-entity option sets with Web API + FetchXml.
 Tested against version 8.2 of the API:

```js
var oDataUrl = 'https://[your_org].crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/';
var encodedFetchXml = encodeURI(`
<fetch top="10" no-lock="true" >
  <entity name="contact" >
    <attribute name="fullname" alias="contactName" />
    <link-entity name="incident" from="customerid" to="contactid" link-type="inner" alias="incident" >
      <attribute name="caseorigincode" alias="incidentOrigin" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
`);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: `${oDataUrl}contacts?fetchXml=${encodedFetchXml}`,
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue");
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    // formatted value included in the response objects
    // incidentOrigin@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue:"WhatsApp"
    console.dir(response); 
});
```

This is the data that is returned:
`{
    "@odata.context":"https://[your_org].crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#contacts(contactid)",
        "value":[{
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"873006\"",
            "contactid": "ecfd1feb-d826-468a-bfe3-6ebd781c39f4",
            "contactName": "Ada Lovelace",
            "incidentOrigin@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "WhatsApp",
            "incidentOrigin": 269420000
        }]
}`

It works with both inner and outer link-types.

**Link-Entity attribute alias named the same as the attribute**
If you make the alias for a linked-entity attribute the same as the attribute name, then the attribute is not returned at all. This problem appears to be for all link-entity attributes.

```xml
<fetch top="500" no-lock="true" >
<entity name="contact" >
    <attribute name="fullname" alias="contactName" />
    <link-entity name="incident" from="customerid" to="contactid" link-type="inner" alias="incident" >
    <attribute name="caseorigincode" alias="caseorigincode" />
    </link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

**Leaving out the link-entity attribute alias**
If you leave out the alias for a linked-entity attribute, it is returned with a horrible name:

```xml
<fetch top="500" no-lock="true" >
<entity name="contact" >
    <attribute name="fullname" alias="contactName" />
    <link-entity name="incident" from="customerid" to="contactid" link-type="inner" alias="incident" >
    <attribute name="caseorigincode" />
    </link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

The returned objects have a field like this:
`incident_x002e_caseorigincode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue:"WhatsApp"`

Maybe the issue you experienced was resolved in version 8.2.